# Converting 24h time into ampm in r to include as x axis label

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2, lubridate

I'm trying to create a graph that has x axis labels as ampm time. However, when I try to recreate the graph with `ggplot2`, I'm unable to use the ampm format.

time<- c("1899-12-31 00:00:00", "1899-12-31 00:10:00", "1899-12-31 00:20:00")
HR <- c("65","67","70")

```
p <- ggplot(data, aes (time, HR)) +
     scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "4 hours", data_labels="%l %p")
```

However, if I try with this time format I get the correct output but with 24h time.

```
p <- ggplot(data, aes (time, HR)) +
     scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "4 hours", data_labels="%H:%M")
```

Time is in POSIXct format and when I use the `lubridate package` to check whether the format could be read as am/pm the output is correct, so I don't know what could be wrong.

Comment: After fixing the typo, i.e. it should be `date_labels` instead of `data_labels` your code works fine. (except that for the range of your example data I had to set the breaks to 1 hour so that at least one break shows up).

Comment: Hi Stefan, you are rigth that I had a type in the writing. However, the problem persists in the sense that I do get the time, but only the value. AMPM does not appear depending on the time (i.e.: 2 instead of 2 am). So, how can I get the ampm part of the time to appear in the label? Thanks!

Comment: Hm. Weird. Using `ggplot(data, aes (time, HR)) + scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "1 hours", date_labels="%l %p")` works fine on my machine and shows one break with label "12 am". But according to the docs the behavior of `%p` is dependent on the locale (See `?strptime` which also includes examples to switch the locale).

Comment: Nothing, it does not show. Not even if I put 1 hours breaks. I've even tried with the parameter %r. The only thing I could try it's to check the timezones to see if may it shows up.